# Nuget creating a folder with the package name

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I created a nuget package "MyClassLib.1.0.0.nupkg" and I am looking to install it in under ClassLib folder of my solution.
However when I install the package it install as below
SolutionFolder\ClassLib\MyClassLib.1.0.0\MyLibraries

Excepted :
**SolutionFolder\ClassLib\MyLibraries**

How can I prevent the folder MyClassLib.1.0.0 from being created.

Note - I use Nuget Package Manager 2.8.6

Comment: you cannot , nuget will download packages with package name and version number folder only. But why you want "SolutionFolder\ClassLib\MyLibraries" this folder structure any reason?

Comment: that's the existing solution structure hence I will not be able to change it.

Comment: do you checkin files in "SolutionFolder\ClassLib\MyLibraries"  this folder into your version control system.. TFS etc..

Comment: Yes, this need to checked in. We need to publish a new nuget for this lib update when we decide to release a new version so that other projects can upgrade it if they need to upgrade.

Comment: I think then you just move those files from "SolutionFolder\ClassLib\MyClassLib.1.0.0\MyLibraries" to "SolutionFolder\ClassLib\MyLibraries" and check that in. nuget will always publish package in a folder with version name. 

How we do is we never check in the nuget packages , they get download during the build with what ever reference we have in package.config file. if somebody wants to update the reference they will simply change the package.config file in the project.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am sure it's doable. Eg:- Manage nuget in a web project, search for jquery in nuget. Install it. It just creates a script folder and downloads the js files in script folder. I am looking for something similar. It doesn't create the unncessary folder structure.

Comment: JQuery is differnt its a file only and also it installs the file with a version number not just plain JQuery.js and also if you see the packages folder it still have the Jquery folder with version like this "jQuery.2.1.3".  you can give a target path in nuspec file of your package but the root of it will always be under a folder with a version may be try skipping the version if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure issue was not the real problem, placing the dlls in the respective folder was the original issue. The below solution may help any newbies.

Writing a power shell script Copy-Item $src $dest -recurse -force inside the install.ps1 copied the contents of the packages into the required folder solved the problem.

Nuget package needs to have a folder named tools and a script file "install.ps1" which is automatically executed everytime the nuget package installation happens.